# 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'formulario'

Tags: django

Saludos, mi duda es la siguiente: necesito filtrar a todos los usuarios que no estén inscritos en un determinado formulario (cuyo id llega del template anterior con un kwarg), planteo los modelos:

```
class UCAUser(AbstractUser):
    dni_cif=models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="DNI/CIF"
    )

class InscripcionRealizada(models.Model):
    formulario = models.ForeignKey(Formulario)
    inscrito = models.ForeignKey(UCAUser,related_name="inscripciones_realizadas")
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Inscripción realizada"
        verbose_name_plural = "Inscripciones realizadas"

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {} - {}".format(self.formulario.programa, self.formulario.edicion, self.inscrito)
```

y la view:

```
class InscribirUsuariosListView(ListView):
    template_name = "inscripciones/InscribirUsuariolist.html"
    model = UCAUser
    group_required = ['Administrador']
    login_url = "auth-login"

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(InscribirUsuariosListView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(UCAUser.inscripciones_realizadas.formulario!=self.kwargs['formulario_id'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(InscribirUsuariosListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formulario_id'] = self.kwargs['formulario_id']
        return context
```

Como podéis ver, la relacion entre `UCAUser` e `InscripcionRealizada` es mediante `Foreignkey`, pero cuando intento hacer el filtro en la vista me sale este error:

> ```
> 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'formulario'
> ```

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: Recuerda que las relaciones foraneas o `ForeignKey` son relaciones de 1 a muchos, lo que quiere decir que tienes un usuario por inscripción pero un usuario, tiene muchas inscripciones, entonces la forma adecuada seria: `UCAUser.inscripcione_realizadas.all()` lo cual te devuelveria un queryset con todas las inscripciones realizadas por el usuario, pero esto no sucederá, porque debe ser pasado a una instancia y no a la clase como tal, por otro lado, me parece que ese filtro de la misma linea del error, está mal, deberías revisarlo.

Comment: Vale gracias, he cambiado el queryset y ahora mismo tengo lo siguiente:

   `def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(InscribirUsuariosListView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(UCAUser.objects.filter(inscripciones_realizadas__formulario=self.kwargs['formulario_id']).exclude())`

Y ahora el error que me da es:" not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: El error es causado por enviar `exclude()` sin parámetros, debes añadirle el campo que quieres excluir, o mejor quitalo si no quieres excluir nada, sin embargo te dije en el comentario anterior que la consulta no funcionaria, luego te arrojará error cuando vaya a resolver el `qs.filter` ya que no estas pasando parámetro de clave valor a partir de el cual va a filtrar

Comment: Hola FangusK, ¿todavía tienes este problema? ¿Tomáste en cuenta las recomendaciones de German?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya conseguí solucionarlo, gracias por vuestra ayuda. Los fallos eran los sugientes:

1. En primer lugar estaba haciendo mal el queryset, porque estaba volviendo a poner el modelo dentro de la búsqueda, sin tener en cuenta que queryset ya me estaba buscando en el modelo.
2. Luego para filtrar como yo necesitaba tenia que ponerlo como exclude.

Os pongo la solución por si os sirve de algo.

Views.py

```
class InscribirUsuariosListView(ListView):
template_name = "inscripciones/InscribirUsuariolist.html"
model = UCAUser
group_required = ['Administrador']
login_url = "auth-login"

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(InscribirUsuariosListView, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.exclude(inscripciones_realizadas__formulario__id=self.kwargs['formulario_id'])

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InscribirUsuariosListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['formulario_id'] = self.kwargs['formulario_id']
    return context
```